# What does network connection duration signify?

Tags: windows, networking

What does the connection duration signify? It always seems to be some random amount of time independent of when I actually connect to or disconnect from a network.

For example, I just connected to my Wi-Fi network 15 minutes ago and the connection status says the connection's duration is `15 days 02:48:10`.

[image: Wireless Network Connection Status]

Answer (score 1):

It is the time length for how long the connection has been active, but I believe for WiFi adapters it only resets if the adapter itself is reset.

I tested this with my WiFi card just now and my behavior is the same as yours unless I physically disconnect the card or disable/re-enable it.